# Is index function in to_csv I have used correctly according to problem statement?

Tags: python-3.x

> Problem Statement :
>
> 1) Create another Series named heights_B from a 1-D numpy array of 5 elements derived from the normal distribution of mean    170.0 and standard deviation 25.0.
>
> Note: Set random seed to 100 before creating heights_B series. Use numpy.
>
> 2) Create another Series named weights_B from a 1-D numpy array of 5 elements derived from the normal distribution of mean    75.0 and standard deviation 12.0.
>
> Note: Set random seed to 100 again before creating weights_B series. Use numpy.
>
> 3)Label both Series elements with s1, s2, s3, s4 and s5.
>
> 4)Create a dataframe df_B containing the height and weight of students s1, s2, s3, s4 and s5 belonging to class B.
>
> 5)Label the columns as Student_height and Student_weight respectively.
>
> Write the contents of df_B without the index to a CSV file named classB.csv.
>
> Note: Use the index argument of to_csv method.
>
> Solution :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
height_A=np.array([176.2,158.4,167.6,156.2,161.4])
s1=pd.Series(height_A,index=['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'])
weight_A=np.array([85.1,90.2,76.8,80.4,78.9])
s2=pd.Series(weight_A,index=['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'])
df={'Student_height':s1,'Student_weight':s2}
hdf=pd.DataFrame(df)
random.seed(100)
x=np.random.normal(loc=170.0,scale=25.0,size=5)
s3=pd.Series(x,index=['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'])
random.seed(100)
y=np.random.normal(loc=75.0,scale=12.0,size=5)
s4=pd.Series(y,index=['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'])
df1=df={'Student_height':s3,'Student_weight':s4}
hdf1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
hdf1.to_csv('classB.csv',index=False)
```

> I have written code according to problem statement but online compiler is not accepting my solution , please tell me if I have done any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

add one more line to code

```
m = pd.read_csv("classB.csv"); print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
import os
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
x=np.random.normal(loc=170.0,scale=25.0,size=5)
np.random.seed(100)
heights_B=pd.Series(x,index=['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'])
np.random.seed(100)
y=np.random.normal(loc=75.0,scale=12.0,size=5)
weights_B=pd.Series(y,index=['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5'])
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'Student_height': heights_B,'Student_weight':weights_B}, index = weights_B.index)
df_B.to_csv("classB.csv",index=False)
os.system("cat classB.csv")
```